# Scipy: Minimize violates given bounds

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` with simple `a <= x <= b` bounds. However, it often happens that my target function is evaluated just outside the bounds. To my understanding, this happens when `minimize` tries to determine the gradient of the target function at the boundary.

---

Minimal example:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, minimize

constraint = Bounds([-1, -1], [1, 1], True)
def fun(x):
    print(x)
    return -math.exp(-np.dot(x,x))
result = minimize(fun, [-1, -1], bounds=constraint)
```

The output shows that the minimizer jumps to the point `[1,1]` and then tries to evaluate at `[1.00000001, 1]`:

```
[-1. -1.]
[-0.99999999 -1.        ]
[-1.         -0.99999999]
[-0.72932943 -0.72932943]
[-0.72932942 -0.72932943]
[-0.72932943 -0.72932942]
[-0.22590689 -0.22590689]
[-0.22590688 -0.22590689]
[-0.22590689 -0.22590688]
[1. 1.]
[1.00000001 1.        ]
[1.         1.00000001]
[-0.03437328 -0.03437328]
...
```

Of course, there is no problem in this example, as `fun` can be evaluated also there. But that might not always be the case...

---

In my actual problem, the minimum can not be on the boundary and I have the easy workaround of adding an epsilon to the bounds.
But one would expect that there should be an easy solution to this issue which also works if the minimum *can* be at a boundary?

PS: It would be strange if I were the first to have this problem -- sorry if this question has been asked before somewhere, but I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You are not the first to encounter this. The answer seems to be [that's what numerical differentiation does](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3056#issuecomment-204802021).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3056#issuecomment-204802021) (thanks @"Welcome to Stack Overflow" for the comment directing me there), the problem is indeed that the gradient routine doesn't respect the bounds.
I wrote a new one that does the job:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def gradient_respecting_bounds(bounds, fun, eps=1e-8):
    """bounds: list of tuples (lower, upper)"""
    def gradient(x):
        fx = fun(x)
        grad = np.zeros(len(x))
        for k in range(len(x)):
            d = np.zeros(len(x))
            d[k] = eps if x[k] + eps <= bounds[k][1] else -eps
            grad[k] = (fun(x + d) - fx) / d[k]
        return grad
    return gradient

bounds = ((-1, 1), (-1, 1))
def fun(x):
    print(x)
    return -math.exp(-np.dot(x,x))
result = minimize(fun, [-1, -1], bounds=bounds,
                  jac=gradient_respecting_bounds(bounds, fun))
```

---

Note that this can be a bit less efficient, because `fun(x)` now gets evaluated twice at each point.
This seems to be unavoidable, relevant snippet from `_minimize_lbfgsb` in lbfgsb.py:

```
if jac is None:
    def func_and_grad(x):
        f = fun(x, *args)
        g = _approx_fprime_helper(x, fun, epsilon, args=args, f0=f)
        return f, g
else:
    def func_and_grad(x):
        f = fun(x, *args)
        g = jac(x, *args)
        return f, g
```

As you can see, the value of `f` can only be reused by the internal `_approx_fprime_helper` function.

Comment: To me it seems you are missing the lower bound, should the function be:


`
            d[k] = eps if (x[k] + eps <= bounds[k][1] and x[k] + eps >= bounds[k][0]) else -eps
`

Comment: @MarkusKaukonen I'm assuming that `eps` is positive and that "x" is not outside the bounds, i.e., `x[k] >= bounds[k][0]`. The second check is then unnecessary.

Comment: Good, I see. I went on for using package https://pypi.org/project/mystic/  to me it seems better than scipy for problems with constraints and bounds.